# Can you prolong someone's life using the Death Note?

Tags: death-note

If you have a 'death note', is it possible to extend your life with it?

Let's say you manipulate someone (let's call them Mike) into getting the Shinigami eyes.  You make Mike write down your date of death (Jan 1st 2022 at 12:00), and you kill him. Let's say you write down that someone will kill you (let's call him Lucas) on Jan 1st 2022 at 11:59.  But on a separate sheet you write down that Lucas also dies on Jan 1st 2022 at 12:00.

What happens? Does Lucas die as he kills you, or does he die before killing you?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/27024/1458) may answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Ryuk explains it clearly.  There are 2 main differences related to the death note between humans and shinigami.  The first is that shinigami can take a human's remaining life force and add it to their own.  The second is that shinigami eyes can see name and lifespan.

Rem also explains clearly that the only way to give a human additional life is if a shinigami falls in love with that human and prevents their death with his death note.

Also, even if the scenario with Lucas could play out with the death note, he still has 60 seconds after your death before his; however, it could be possible, if you knew Lucas was planning to kill you at a certain time, to write his name and prevent him from succeeding.

So, in summary, it is not possible to extend your life with a death note without prior knowledge of the future, and also just having a death note means that even if someone made the eye deal, they wouldn't see your lifespan as that is how Misa Amane knew that Light Yagami was Kira.

Answer (score -1):

In my belief, I don't think you can. The only way to actually do that is to destroy the paper before the person dies because the death note kills, it doesn't help stay alive.